# Utf8mb4 issue uploading to 1and1.com

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, phpmyadmin

I have been trying to upload my local mamp site to 1and1 for about three weeks now and I keep getting errors regarding utf8mb4 errors. Their servers only host utf8 code instead of utf8mb4 along with many other web hosts. How am I supposed to get around this issue while exporting my files when phpmyadmin forces me to use utf8mb4 when I need utf8? The database server I am running for mamp is version 5.5.38, while 1and1's database version is 5.1.73. The phpmyadmin I am using through mamp is the newest 4.4.9 version while their version is 4.1.14.8. Is there a way to downgrade my mamp tools so that it will be able to work with 1and1 servers? Or is there another way I can get around this without having to redo about a month of work? I know it is a problem with the SQL database export from the mamp version of phpmyadmin and when I try to switch it all the utf8, it won't let me. Please point me in the right direction here with a link to the right version I need, or steps to fix the problem. I have literally tried everything from downgrading phpmyadmin to trying to use MYSQL40 to make it compatible. And nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL 5.5.3 was the first to support utf8mb4, if you need utf8mb4 support you'll have to find a host that has at least MySQL 5.5.3.

Or, in order to prevent the errors, you should do your local work using utf8, not utf8mb4.

When you say "when I try to switch it all the utf8, it won't let me" please describe what the exact problem is. I was able to use the Change link on the table Structure page to change collations from `utf8mb4_swedish_ci` to `utf8_swedish_ci`, export from a 5.6 server to a 5.1 server, and see the data without trouble.

On my 5.6 server, I'm able to change the database collation from the database Operations tab, the table collation from the table Operations tab, and the column collation through the Change link on the table Structure tab without any error or problems.

It's also interesting to note that phpMyAdmin 4.1.14.8 is no longer supported; for your use with an old MySQL server the 4.0 series is the best choice; the latest version at the moment is 4.0.10.10. This probably isn't the cause of your problems, but I feel compelled to point it out anyway.